# How to associate a filename with a variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Instead of:

```
=ZÄHLENWENN([B16.xlsx]ListeVU!$Y:$Y;F5)
```

I would like to have like:

```
=ZÄHLENWENN(["C6".xlsx]ListeVU!$Y:$Y;F5)
```

But this does not work.

[image]

Comment: For those wondering: `ZÄHLENWENN()` = `COUNTIF()`. On-topic: You should use `INDIRECT()` to concatenate these values from `C6` in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mean like: ```=ZÄHLENWENN(INDIREKT([C6.xlsx])ListeVU!$Y:$Y;F5)```
It does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment you'd need to use `INDIRECT()`. The right syntax would be:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'["&C6&".xlsx]ListeVU'!$Y:$Y"),F5)
```

Or in german:

```
=ZÄHLENWENN(INDIREKT("'["&C6&".xlsx]ListeVU'!$Y:$Y");F5)
```